# Is there a way to pass variable to php string with pattern

Tags: php, string

Is there a way to pass patterns to php string this way?

```
$pattern['first'] = "some text $var1";
$pattern['secound'] = "some text $var2";

$var1 = 10;
$var2 = 'text';

$string = " some text {$pattern['first']} some text {$pattern['secound'] = "some text $var2";}";
```

Comment: I'd look into a templating package such as Twig.

Comment: For something not too complex then [sprintf — Return a formatted string](http://php.net/sprintf) may be useful. As already suggested, for more complex formatting then a 'template engine' may be useful, of which there are many. I use PHP as a 'templating engine'.